# How to update postgres uri value in cf vcaps env

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a bound Postgres service to my spring application in CF (Cloud foundry)
The VCAPS env available are as following:

```
"postgresql": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {
     "dbname": "JDusZ6EpE1ixbTKS",
     "end_points": [
      {
       "host": "10.11.241.2",
       "network_id": "SF",
       "port": "46371"
      }
     ],
     "hostname": "10.11.241.2",
     "password": "SuVzOf2m5L5oNYSG",
     "port": "46371",
     "ports": {
      "5432/tcp": "46371"
     },
     "uri": "postgres://eyv6avf27X9Z55Gx:SuVzOf2m5L5oNYSG@10.11.241.2:46371/JDusZ6EpE1ixbTKS",
     "username": "eyv6avf27X9Z55Gx"
    },
    "instance_name": "mypostgres",
    "label": "postgresql",
    "name": "mypostgres",
    "plan": "v9.6-dev",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [
     "postgresql",
     "relational"
    ],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ],
```

I need to modefy the value of the uri to include also the current schema, I guess it needs to be as:

```
 "uri": "postgres://eyv6avf27X9Z55Gx:SuVzOf2m5L5oNYSG@10.11.241.2:46371/JDusZ6EpE1ixbTKS?currentSchema=mycurrentschema"
```

Is this something possible to do? and If not what is the best practice to assign current schema for a spring app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. You can talk to your service provider, the operator of the service broker from which you are obtaining your service. The service broker is the one that sets the credentials, so you could ask them to include the schema by default.
2. You can create a service key with `cf create-service-key`. The service key is like a service binding, but free floating so it's not attached to your app. It just exists as long as the service key exists. You can then create a user provided service, with `cf cups` and manually set whatever credentials or uri you require for your app. The downside of this approach is that you have to do a little more work to manage the service information.
3. You can read the current uri into your application and modify it before creating your DataSource. This is not particularly easy if you are using Spring Cloud Connectors because it handles creating the DataSource for you. I would not recommend using SCC.

   Instead you can do this with the Spring Boot [CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/cloud/CloudFoundryVcapEnvironmentPostProcessor.html) and property place holders. See the referenced Javadoc for how that works.

   The other option is to use [java-cvenv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv). That provides you with an easy way to obtain credentials information, like the URL and use that to create your own DataSource, which allows you to make slight modifications to things like the URL, if necessary.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel. Your answer is very helpful, Thank you so much for the clear explanation