# Datasource object is overridden with cloud foundry configurations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a spring boot application bound to a DB service instance (postgres) in a cloud foundry environment.
The VCAPs of the application includes the following binding:

```
"postgresql": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {
     "dbname": "yD6nAoGVmfmqnbex",
     "end_points": [
      {
       "host": "10.11.241.0",
       "network_id": "SF",
       "port": "50257"
      }
     ],
     "hostname": "10.11.241.0",
     "password": "No963ndbbsfndJoj",
     "port": "50257",
     "ports": {
      "5432/tcp": "50257"
     },
     "uri": "postgres://Gw7n8pHTvpM2gh7t:No963ndbbsfndJoj@10.11.241.0:50257/yD6nAoGVmfmqnbex",
     "username": "Gw7n8pHTvpM2gh7t"
    },
    "instance_name": "cispostgres",
    "label": "postgresql",
    "name": "cispostgres",
    "plan": "v9.6-dev",
    "provider": null,
    "syslog_drain_url": null,
    "tags": [
     "postgresql",
     "relational"
    ],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
```

When I start the application, cloud foundry is creating a DataSource object and put it in the context of spring with the exact configurations from the previous vcaps as expected.

Following another issue: [How to update postgres uri value in cf vcaps env](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57474030/how-to-update-postgres-uri-value-in-cf-vcaps-env)

I'm trying to override the Datasource neam object to be able to concat the schema name of the DB to the url as follow:

```
@Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource createDataSource() throws SQLException {

        String dbUri = "jdbc:postgresql://10.11.241.0:50257/yD6nAoGVmfmqnbex?currentSchema=accounts";
        String username = "Gw7n8pHTvpM2gh7t";
        String password = "No963ndbbsfndJoj";

        DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(dbUri)
                .username(username)
                .password(password)
                .type(org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource.class)
                .driverClassName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME)
                .build();
        return dataSource;
    }
```

Unfortenatly, cloud founday seems to be overriding my bean and creates a new one after my bean was created.

when i perform the following CF command:

```
$ cf us myapp mypostgres
$ cf restart myapp
```

My bean is not beeing overredien, and it works fine.
I'm trying to find a way to cancel the auto configuration done by the cloud foundary or whatever is doing that for me.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple ways to opt out of auto reconfiguration.

1. You can opt out of just auto reconfiguration if your application has Java config that extends from `AbstractCloudConfig`, or if you define an `@Bean` which is of type `Cloud`. In either case, the auto reconfiguration should see that you're doing manual configuration and back off.

   This isn't well documented, but the [first two sections here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_the_java_configuration) allude to it.
2. You can completely disable auto reconfiguration be setting the env variable `JBP_CONFIG_SPRING_AUTO_RECONFIGURATION` to be `{ enabled: false }`. This will completely turn auto reconfiguration. See [docs here for reference](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-spring_auto_reconfiguration.md#configuration).

The main difference between the two options is that the latter tells the Java buildpack to not even install auto reconfiguration, which means you lose a couple additional features like the `cloud.services` property placeholders and the automatic addition of the `cloud` Spring profile.

I personally prefer option #2, as I don't use the `cloud.services` property place holders and it's easy enough to enable the cloud profile by adding an env variable `SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE` and setting it to `cloud`, assuming you need that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for your reply, I think for my case it's better to use the first option you mentioned since I don't want to lose the other cloud features. All that I'm trying to do is to add the ?=currentSchema to the database url so I can make the DataSource works with a specific schema instead of the default one.